# Trouble loading viewForSectionHeader from a XIB

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

I really want to have full control of section headers by laying out in a XIB using Interface Builder.

I'm using the code below, but my titleLabel.text is not changing when I run the app.  It continues to show the default "Label" text for each section header.   I've NSLog'd the value of headerText and it does contain the proper string.

Any ideas?  Thank you

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    CustomSectionHeaderViewController *cshvc = [[CustomSectionHeaderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomSectionHeaderViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    NSString *headerText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sectionInfo name]];

    cshvc.titleLabel.text = headerText;

    return cshvc.view;
}
```

UPDATED WITH ANSWER:
Here's how I got it working after reading Tammo's answer

```
CustomSectionHeader *cshv = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomSectionHeader" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

   id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

NSString *headerText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sectionInfo name]];

cshv.textLabel.text = headerText;


return cshv;
```

Comment: Did you connect `titleLabel` property to the title label in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't think having a controller for that kind of view is the right thing to do.

The problem with your code is that the controller loads the view only when needed. When accessing titleLabel, the view is not loaded yet, so titleLabel is nil. Try

```
NSString *headerText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sectionInfo name]];

// Make sure that the view is loaded
UIView *result = [cshvc view];

cshvc.titleLabel.text = headerText;

return result;
```